# bootstrap_form error undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

1- I installed gem bootstrap_form
2- I wrote in application.css that line `*= require bootstrap_form before the */`
3- in my html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@guardian, :url => student_guardians_path(@student),
html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },
method: :post) do |f| %>
```

And I am getting the following error : `undefined method`bootstrap_form_for' for #<#:0xb31a80c>`

Comment: did you add the gem in your Gemfile ?

Comment: yes but not in a specific group , just wrote it in the top of my gem file

Comment: try bootstrap_form_for([@student,@guardian]......and remove the url,u dont need it as u are binding the form with object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by writing the form's code correctly as shown in @sunny1304's comment `bootstrap_form_for([@student,@guardian]`. So if none of the existing answers worked for you this might be a hint or something to guide you.

Thanks to other contributors as their answers helped other users who faced the issue like me.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error. Fixed it by replacing

```
gem 'bootstrap-form'
```

by

```
gem 'bootstrap_form'
```

in my `gemfile`

Comment: Yeah this was my problem. I coulda sworn it said in the docks to use a dash instead of an underscore. Doh!

Answer (score 5):

I too was getting this error until I realized that I didn't restart the rails server. When I restarted the server, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this issue and my problem was that bundle install seemed to be pulling v3.0.0, yet the most recent version on GitHub is listed as 2.3.0. Changing the appropriate line in my Gemfile to:

```
gem 'bootstrap_form', '~> 2.3.0'
```

Fixed the issue.